# Show grouping from selectInput with list

Tags: r, shiny

In the code below, the output of the selectInput is just the choice, but not the grouping variable too. I'd like to be able to say what grouping it came from as well. Example `You Chose Gender - Female`. How can pull the grouping variable out of this?

```
if (interactive()) {

  # basic example


  # demoing optgroup support in the `choices` arg
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                  list(`State` = c("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                       `Gender` = c("Female","Male"),
                       `Region` = c("North", "West", "East"))
      ),
      textOutput("result")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$result <- renderText({
        paste("You chose", input$state)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
library(purrr) # install.packages('purrr')
library(shiny)

choices <- list(
  `State` = c("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
  `Gender` = c("Female","Male"),
  `Region` = c("North", "West", "East")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "state",
      "Choose a state:",
      choices <- choices
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste(
        "You chose",
        input$state,
        "from",
        names(choices)[choices %>% map_lgl(~input$state %in% .)]
      )
    })
  }
)
```

There is a potential issue when having duplicate options under different categories though. This can be addressed by using name and value(unique across the whole list) pairs as list elements. See below.

```
# 'Region' and 'Direction' both have an option 'North' but can be distinguished by the value. Note you should use values in your app logic.

library(purrr) # install.packages('purrr')
library(shiny)
choices <- list(
  State = c("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
  Gender = c("Female", "Male"),
  Region = c("North" = "reg_north", "West" = "reg_west", "East" = "reg_east"),
  Direction = c("North" = "dir_north", "South" = "dir_south")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "state", "Choose a state:",
      choices <- choices
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste(
        "You chose",
        input$state,
        "from",
        names(choices)[choices %>% map_lgl(~input$state %in% .)]
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: interesting! I haven't seen this package before. Thanks!

Comment: @TedMosby This is one of the 'tidyverse' packages for iteration which I think is super useful when doing functional programming.

Comment: How could I enable this to allow for multiple selections? I.E, State and Gender picked? The output would ideally be a data.frame with 2 columns

Comment: Separate your input to different selectInput and merge the results into a data frame.

Comment: Let say I wanted to use your option 2, how can I automatically make the named list for each column in the data set?

Comment: @TedMosby Do you mean convert a data frame to a named list? What does the dataset look like?